# How to get Google+ views per post?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-plus

I would like to write some Apps Script to get analytics information about who viewed my posts in G+.  I am pretty sure that information exists as the Influence dialog has view counts.  However, the [activities resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities#resource) API does not list views anywhere and I do not see any other applicable API.

Does anyone know how to get this information?

Comment: [`listByActivity`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/listByActivity) isn't what you want? It's possible the data you think is in Google plus is coming from some other Google project.

Comment: It seems that call only supports "plusoners" and "resharers", not viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Google+ doesn't surface page views in it's APIs. The data listed on [Activity resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities#resource) is what's available.